# variable crop option with add_image_size()

Tags: images, cropping

In my child Theme I have set my custom image with `add_image_size( 'big', 1500, 1000 )`
I left out the crop parameter, but it is [false by default][1] anyway.

I want to make this a variable option.

I have just written a plugin that displays all the registered image sizes (including WP's *thumbnail*, *medium* and *large* sizes) plus my custom size.

With checkboxes I do `update_option($_size."_crop", true)` for WP's image sizes and `global $_wp_additional_image_sizes; $_wp_additional_image_sizes[$_size]['crop'] = true` for my custom size.

The *thumbnail*, *medium* and *large* work all fine but I can't get to override the default false $crop parameter from `add_image_size`?
When I `var_dump($_wp_additional_image_sizes;)` on my plugin page the boolean displays true, but when I upload a new image it is like `add_image_size()` wins over my plugin?

When I set `add_image_size( 'big', 1500, 1000, true)` in functions.php everything works like I want, but I want to make it an option to switch between hard and soft cropping - from my plugin options page obviously.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have found out a way to do this. With the plugin, with some checkboxes I am setting a crop option in the db in wp_options table, just like WP does it for the thumbnail, medium and large sizes.

So my big image sets the `add_option('big_crop', true)`

Than in functions.php I do:

```
if ( get_option( "big_crop" ) == true ) {
    add_image_size( 'big', 1500, 1000, true );  
} else {
    add_image_size( 'big', 1500, 1000, false ); 
}
```